# Console: Disable Shift+ArrowKeys (Text selection mode)

Tags: c#, c++, cmd, windows-console

Is it possible to disable the text selection mode in the windows console for the current application?

With 'text selection mode', I mean that pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and an arrow key (e.g. <kbd>Left</kbd>) will be interpreted by the console host as a text selection comannd instead of being forwarded as a `KeyPressedEvent` to the running application.

I know that it is possible to disable the 'Quick Edit Mode' using the `SetConsoleMode`-function inside `kernel32.dll`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void* GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(void* hWnd, ConsoleMode dwMode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(void* hWnd, ConsoleMode* lpMode);

[Flags]
public enum ConsoleMode
    : uint
{
    // ...
    ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x0040,
    // ...
}


static void DisableQEMode()
{
    void* ptr = GetStdHandle(-10);
    ConsoleMode mode;

    GetConsoleMode(ptr, &mode);
    SetConsoleMode(ptr, mode & ~ConsoleMode.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);
}
```

This, however, does not solve my problem. The key input <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> will still not be forwarded to my application.

Did I miss setting other console flags?

*(My application is written in C#, however, a C++ solution is also fine by me.)*

Comment: Go to properties by right clicking titlebar and disable Extended Text Selection Keys.

Comment: Which is different to Quick Edit Mode (QEM allows to use of the mouse to mark text without selecting Mark from the Edit menu).

Comment: @Mark: I could do that, however, I have to solve this issue programmatically -- not "by hand".

Comment: I suspect its a user preference setting so there won't be one. Quick Edit Mode has lots of compatibility issues. _**Low-Level Console Input Functions**
A console's input buffer contains input records that can include information about keyboard, mouse, buffer-resizing, focus, and menu events. The low-level functions provide direct access to the input buffer, unlike the high-level functions that filter and process the input buffer's data, discarding all but keyboard input._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/low-level-console-input-functions